# How to link to a local plugin with phonegap 3.6.3

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

My problem is that I want to use this [plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1369), however it currently breaks the android build. The issue is "fixed" in an unmerged [merge request](https://github.com/donaldp24/CanvasCameraPlugin/pull/7) but the user hasn't logged in for a long time and it doesn't look like the change is going to be merged anytime soon.  So I cloned the repo and applied the fixes locally.

Now, I want to link to this plugin locally in my config.xml file at the root of my phonegap project.  I do not want to re release the plugin because I won't be able to support it but I just want to use it locally for testing purposes.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using `build.phonegap.com` or building locally with the command line interface?

Comment: I am using build.phonegap.com but I am more then willing to switch to the CLI if need be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you switch to local development, you can install the plugin like this:

```
cordova plugin add /path/to/the/plugin/folder
```

Comment: looks like I have to switch from their build tool, seems like it isn't so magical after all.  Thanks! (I am very new to mobile development and phonegap)

Comment: if you have a paid phonpegap build plan you can upload the plugin for private use